# LibGDX: Change ApplicationConfiguration (sampling) at runtime

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX and I have set the amount of samples in my ApplicationConfiguration to 8:

```
cfg.samples = 8;
```

When I draw circles or diagonal lines everyting looks nice, but on straight lines with a thickness of 1 it looks like this:

[image: picture 1]

But it *should* look like this (as you can imagine, this is not a screenshot, i made this manually in gimp ;) ):

[image: picture 2]

My idea is to disable the sampling, draw the straight lines and enable it afterwards. But for this I have to change the `ApplicationConfiguration` right? Is this possible and if so, how? Or is there another / a better way to solve this?

Comment: You can't do this because it requires the GLSurface to be recreated each time you change the number of samples.

Comment: Maybe try aligning your straight lines with the pixels on the screen so they are effectively left unchanged by AA.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I thought so :/ and how do I do this alignment with the ShapeRenderer I'm using?

Comment: Solved my problem with a workaround: Instead of the `ShapeRenderer` I use a 1x1 texture to create straight lines.